# How to sort all the data by date in google apps script?

Tags: date, sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have retrieved the data from REST API and inserted into google apps script but i am not sure how to sort the data based on the subscription date. I have used the sort() but it is only sorting one column instead of everything. This is my current code and screenshot so far:

```
function myFunction() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName("test")

  var apiKey = 'test';

  var URL_STRING = "";

  var url = URL_STRING + "?ApiKey=" + apiKey;

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  var firstname = [];
  var lastname = [];
  var subscriptionDate = [];

  for (var i=0;i<data.output.o1.length;i++){
    fn=(data.output.o1[i].first_name);
    firstname.push([fn]);

    ln=(data.output.o1[i].last_name);
    lastname.push([ln]);

    sd=(data.output.o1[i].subscription_date);
    subscriptionDate.push([sd]);
     };

  mainSheet.getRange(2, 1, firstname.length).setValues(firstname);
  mainSheet.getRange(2, 2, lastname.length).setValues(lastname);
  mainSheet.getRange(2, 3, subscriptionDate.length).setValues(subscriptionDate);

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, how about sorting the values when the array for putting to Spreadsheet is created? When this is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
var firstname = [];
var lastname = [];
var subscriptionDate = [];

for (var i=0;i<data.output.o1.length;i++){
  fn=(data.output.o1[i].first_name);
  firstname.push([fn]);

  ln=(data.output.o1[i].last_name);
  lastname.push([ln]);

  sd=(data.output.o1[i].subscription_date);
  subscriptionDate.push([sd]);
   };

mainSheet.getRange(2, 1, firstname.length).setValues(firstname);
mainSheet.getRange(2, 2, lastname.length).setValues(lastname);
mainSheet.getRange(2, 3, subscriptionDate.length).setValues(subscriptionDate);
```

#### To:

```
var values = data.output.o1.map(({first_name, last_name, subscription_date}) => [first_name, last_name, subscription_date]);
values.sort((a, b) => new Date(a[2]).getTime() > new Date(b[2]).getTime() ? 1 : -1);
mainSheet.getRange(2, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

- When `values.sort((a, b) => new Date(a[2]).getTime() > new Date(b[2]).getTime() ? 1 : -1);` is modified to `values.sort((a, b) => new Date(a[2]).getTime() > new Date(b[2]).getTime() ? -1 : 1);`, the order of sort direction is changed.

#### Note:

- As other method, when the following script to the bottom of your current script, the sort is run with the column "C".

  ```
    mainSheet.getRange("A2:C").sort([{ column: 3, ascending: true }]);
  ```
- In this answer, from your sample image, I supposed that your column "C" is the date object.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
- [sort(sortSpecObj)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sortsortspecobj)

Answer (score 2):

mainSheet.getRange(2,1,mainSheet.getLastRow()-1,3).sort({column:3,ascending:true});